# C++ setting reference variable in a class and afterwards changing

Tags: c++

Say I have a class Foo with a reference variable of type Bar and a constructor like so:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Bar& m_b;

    Foo(Bar& b);
}
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(Bar& b) : m_b(b) {
}
```

And in a separate class I have:

```
// global 
Bar b; 
Foo f(b);

int main() {   
  b.setData();       // actually set some values...
  f.m_b.showData();  // will it show the change?
  return 0; 
}
```

Will the reference variable in f also have that change of data after setData() is called?  I am trying this work-around because I have a class that has a reference variable (which must be set during initialization) but I need it to be globally accessible (declared before actually setting the data in Bar).

Comment: A bit off topic, but a globally available class that contains a reference variable smells funny. If you can't avoid the global, could you make it a non-const reference, and just use f.setData()?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `f.mb` and `b` both refer to the same object.

Comment: Thanks!  I just wanted to make sure, as this is part of a much larger program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. A reference is just an alias. `f::m_b` and `b` are *exactly the same object*.